# scheduling execution of MS Access DB

Tags: ms-access, macros, scheduling, execution

I have a MS Access 2007 DB that is being executed via Windows NT scheduler.   Basically, I created this entry in Windows Scheduler that is run every night at midnight.

I:\Case_Management_Systems\TRIAL_UNIT\Docket_Sheets_Tracking.accdb   /x USER_LOG_REPORT_DELETE

The above statement opens the DB and executes the /x macro to print a report and delete some records.

Everything is fine, except that the DB has a password and when windows scheduler executes the statement, it opens the db and the DB prompts for the password.  Since there is no one around to enter the password, the execution has to wait until morning when I get in and provide the password.  Once the password is provided, the execution goes flawless.

I believe that before MS Access 2007 there was a /passw parameter where the password could be provided as part of the execution entry just like the macro above, but in MS Acess 2007 the /passw parameter is not allowed.

I was wondering if anyone knows a way around the password so that i can integrate it to the windows scheduler and the db can be opened at midnight when no one is here to provide the password . . . . . . .

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `/pwd` command line switch (see [How to use command-line switches in Microsoft Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209207)), but that is only for a ULS (user-level) security password. There is no command-line switch option for a *database* password.

You could create a `VBScript` to automate an Access session.  The `Application.OpenCurrentDatabase Method` allows you to supply the database password when you open the db file within that session.  And you can use the `DoCmd.RunMacro Method` to run your macro.

Finally, schedule the `VBScript` file in the task scheduler.

Here is a simple VBScript example to get you started.  Change the values of the constants to match your situation.

```vb
Option Explicit
Const cstrDb = "C:\path\YourDbFile.mdb"
Const cstrPwd = "YourPassword"
Const cstrMacro = "YourMacroName"
Dim oAccess

Set oAccess= CreateObject("Access.Application")
oAccess.Visible = True
oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase cstrDb, False, cstrPwd
oAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro cstrMacro
oAccess.Quit
```

Comment: thanks a lot.  i am not familiar with the method you described but i will certainly research it. Thanks again.

Comment: I added a sample script.  It's pretty basic, but I doubt you need anything more complicated.

Comment: However, the mapped drive letter might be an obstacle.  Use a UNC path instead: `\\Server\ShareName\folders_if_any\Docket_Sheets_Tracking.accdb` and make that location trusted in the trust center or digitally sign the db file.

Comment: thanks a lot for the code.  That helps tremendously.  I will appreciate your help again.  I copied the code you provided and modified accordingly see:

Comment: Msg1 = msgbox ("Start process",,"Delete user log records")
   Option Explicit
   Const cstrDb    = "I:\Case_Management_Systems\TRIAL_UNIT\Docket_Sheets_Tracking.accdb"
   Const cstrPwd   = "Docket1"
   Const cstrMacro = "USER_LOG_REPORT_DELETE"
 
   Dim oAccess
   Set oAccess= CreateObject("Access.Application")

   oAccess.Visible = True
   oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase cstrDb, False, cstrPwd
   oAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro cstrMacro
   oAccess.Quit

   Msg2 = msgbox ("So far ",,"Delete user log records")

Comment: however, i get a compilation error message  indicating line 5 char 4 expected statement . . . . . .  on the very first statement Option Explicit . . . . .   sorry i do not know how to put the code in here in a neat way, whenever i do enter to create a new line, it sends the comment

Comment: Yeah, you can't use line breaks in Stack Overflow comments.  `Option Explicit` requires you declare all your variables, but you added `Msg1` and `Msg2` without `Dim` --- that should fail.  Can you please start by testing my simpler example and just changing the values of the constants as I suggested?  That way we will both be working with the same code --- code that I've already tested.  Put your enhancements on the back burner until after we can confirm the very simplest script works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.   I managed to get a clean compilation using your code.   It works like a charm and what is better, you wrote the code in such a clean and simple way that even I am able to understand what is doing.   It already tested and will put in production.  Just making some minor changes to the macro.  I really appreciate all your help.  It is working now, your code works great.